# how to select orphan records from model where referential integrity is not enforced?

Tags: django, django-models

Given the following models implemented in sqlite3

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass

class Children(models.Model):
    parent=models.ForeignKey(Parent,primary_key=True)
```

After importing data from a spreadsheet into Children I need to get a list of Parents having no children and for this I'm using...

```
Parent.objects.filter(children__isnull=True)
```

which seems to work fine.

But because referential integrity is not enforced I also need a list of Children having no Parent and for this I'm trying...

```
Children.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
```

which returns an empty queryset even though some are orphans?
Any pointers as to the best way of achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, I know I can pick up the orphans during the import process but this would not suit my purpose so well.

Comment: what you have should work. are you positive that there are no orphans?

Comment: There is one orphan deliberately inserted for test purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that Django allows nested querying:

```
def Foo(request):
    parent_ids=Parent.objects.values('id')
    orphans=Children.objects.exclude(parent_id__in=parent_ids)
    return render_to_response('Foo.html', {'orphans':orphans})
```

Answer (score 1):

**No answers yet so here's my attempt to answer my own question**

Here is an ugly solution that works...

```
def Foo(request):
    orphans=[]
    for child in Children.objects.all():
        try:
            if child.parent:
                pass
        except Parent.DoesNotExist:
            orphans.append(child)
    return render_to_response('Foo.html',{'orphans':orphans})
```

Hopefully there is a better way?

---

**Update** improved method...

```
def Foo(request):
    parent_id_list=[row.pk for row in Parent.objects.all()]
    orphans=Children.objects.exclude(pk__in=parent_id_list)
    return render_to_response('Foo.html',{'orphans':orphans})
```